# Sendkeys.SendWait C#

Tags: c#, paste

I am trying to click a button in a Windows Form Application and use the `SendKeys` function in C# to write `button1.Text` to a separate window. Kind of like a "paste" function. However, when I use `SendKeys.SendWait`, it writes the text incorrectly. For instance, the button1.Text = "Hello World!"

It will paste "HHHelloo Worlddd!!"

Is there a way I can get the exact string to send over?

Here's a sample of what's going on:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Visible = false;
        SendKeys.SendWait(button1.Text);
        this.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: what exactly is that "separate window"?

Comment: Read the [part of the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that talk about `appSettings`.  And do stop using this blight to humanity.

Comment: @muratgu The separate window could be a text editor or an email...anywhere that text can be entered.

Comment: @Hans I will try to add that to the config file. Thanks. Do you have a recommendation on something else with similar functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution to this problem. Instead of sending the text one key at a time and using the extra xml in the config file, you can simply call `SendKeys.SendWait("^(v)");` to simulate Paste.